# Create Dialog-link popup for text message link HandcentSMS

Tags: android, dialog, sms

I'm in the middle of modifying a test message application and one of the features that I'd like to add to it would be that when a text message is received, a dialog box of some sort would pop up with the text message stuff and the ability to quickly reply to it, all without having to go into the actual application. Taking HandcentSMS as an example, here is what I'm talking about:

[image: Quick Text reply]

Any ideas how to go about doing this, or could anyone point me in a good direction to get started on this?

Comment: `smspopup` does something similar and it is open source: code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make an activity, and style it with custom style which should inherit Theme.Dialog
Example style:

```
<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:drawable/alert_light_frame</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>            
        <item name="android:overScrollMode">never</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

The most important thing is to prepare xml layout of the activity properly.
I suggest to WRAP_CONTENT for everything vertically, and FILL_PARENT horizontally.

Sample layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="280dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frg_alert_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/topbar_logo"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Title"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/customPanel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/custom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/messagePanel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/message"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text"/>
    </ScrollView>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frg_alert_three_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="3">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_positive"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:text="Button"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_neutral"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Button"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_negative"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frg_alert_two_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/screenPadding"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_positive"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:text="Button"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_negative"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:text="Button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

for Create this UI just Create an Activity with background transparent as:

**Step 1:** add res\values\style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.Smspopuptheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>  
</resources>
```

**Step 2:** add theme to in `AndroidManifest.xml` for activity which u want to show with message as:

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.D1NoTitleDim"
    android:name=".SmspopuptestActivity" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Step 3:** In SmspopuptestActivity.java set `FEATURE_NO_TITLE` before `setContentView` as:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Remove notification bar
    //this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

**Step 4:** Your Activity layout look like `res/layout/main.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#55000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frg_alert_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:weightSum="3">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

add your layout elements in frg_alert_buttons likes Buttons, Textviews,Imageview and EditViews as per your need.

Start  SmspopuptestActivity.java Activity when you receive new SMS.

**Some helpful resources:**

[android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/)

SOME SOUCE CODE FOR SMSPOPUP IN ANDROID:

[droid-notify](http://code.google.com/p/droid-notify/source/browse/trunk/src/apps/droidnotify/QuickReplyActivity.java)

[android-smspopup](http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/source/browse/SMSPopup/src/net/everythingandroid/smspopup/ui/SmsPopupActivity.java)

[showsms](http://code.google.com/p/showsms/source/browse/trunk/src/com/bydavy/android/showsms/QuickReplyActivity.java)

[smspopup-for-android](http://code.google.com/p/smspopup-for-android/source/browse/trunk/smspopup/src/net/everythingandroid/smspopup/SmsPopupActivity.java)

Comment: Just what I was looking for, adding it as a launcher activity was a nice touch too. Thanks!